# How to trigger visual effects of hover without showing a hover tooltip

Tags: python, bokeh, heatmap, highlight

I have a large heatmap in which I plot the cells via `p.image` with a hover that shows the exact values.
Additionally, when hovering over a region the region should be highlighted with an outline. A `p.rect` with only `hover_outline_alpha=1` works exactly as I want it, but additionally it shows a hover tooltip. Is there any way to disable the hover tooltip while still having the visual changes triggered?

```
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

image = [np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]])]
p = figure(x_range=["aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"], y_range=["aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"], 
           tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])

# heatmap 
image_renderer = p.image(image=image, x=0, y=0, dw=4, dh=4, palette=Viridis256)

# outlines for each region
rect_renderer = p.rect(x=[1, 1, 3, 3], y=[1, 3, 1, 3], width=2, height=2, 
       fill_alpha=0.0, line_alpha=0.0, hover_line_alpha=1, line_width=3)


# Disables the tooltip on rect_renderer, but also does not trigger the outline
p.hover.renderers = [image_renderer]
# Seperate hover triggers the hover, but also shows an empty tooltip.
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[rect_renderer], tooltips=""))

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [cross posted](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/how-to-trigger-visual-effects-of-hover-without-showing-a-hover-tooltip/7155) this question to the bokeh discourseforum and bryan answered:

> Set toolips=None, not the empty string. This is documented at the bottom of the reference guide entry for tooltips:
>
> ```
> None is also a valid value for tooltips. This turns off the rendering of tooltips.
> ```